# How to change frame layout background and text in other method, which we have added in ocreate() method of the same activity class?

Tags: android

/****How to change frame layout background and text in other method onclick listener, which we have added in ocreate() method of the same activity class?  */**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Acitvity{ 

               public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){    
                     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
                     setContentView(R.layout.mainView);     **//Main view**  
                     final FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById    (R.id.mainViewRootLayout);    
                     FrameLayout ribbonLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainribbonLayout);    
                     TextView ribbonText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainribbonLayoutText);    
                     ribbonText.setText("MainRibbonViewBeforeClick");  

                     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService     (context.Layout_Inflater_service);   

                    addRow(rootLayout);  
             }  
            }

    /*Here is the calling method in same class which adds one more text view, if we click on text view the ribbon text of oncreate method has to be changed*/ 


      public void addRow(FrameLayout rootLayout)
           {
          Rect rect = new Rect();
          rootLayout.getDrawingRect(rect);
          FrameLayout ribbonLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.subRibbonLayout);
          TextView subText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subribbonLayoutText);
          subText.setText("ClicktoChangeTheRibbon");
          subText.setOnclickListener(new onClickListener()  **//Setting up the listener 
         {   
         public vid onclick(View v){     
          FrameLayout ribbonLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainribbonLayout);   

                     TextView ribbonText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainribbonLayoutText);    
                     ribbonText.setText("SubRibbonAfterClick");  


                  /*Here I need to implement a code that changes the ribbon text which I have added in onCreate method*/  
                     }  
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create

```
FrameLayout ribbonLayout 
TextView ribbonText
```

above the  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) line.
It will create variable lifetime for whole activity. SO in activity anywhere you will able to access it.

Currently your created objects are available only for onCreate method.

Comment: Thanks SharpDeveloper, This is also working.. I have posted one more question,, Actually I need it rectified sooner.. Could you please have a look on it?